# Extra shoes for Inline Skating

Tags: shoes, travel, sports

I skate around the city sometimes, but out of courtesy (and sometimes the law) I can't wear my skates indoors, so I must switch to shoes.

Is there good way to carry shoes around, aside from jamming bulky sneakers in my bag?

Comment: Part 1 is off topic as that is basically just a product recommendation. I would recommend that you remove that part. Also, Post are typically better when they focus around one core question rather than 2.

Comment: @DangerZone I figured the first part was ok as I was asking for a type of shoe as opposed to a brand, but removing that part of the question shouldn't invalidate the current answer so I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shoes I'm used to calling "Chinese shoes" (also sometimes called "Kung Fu shoes", easily found in any Chinatown in America or Europe) can be folded flat or rolled to fit in a large pocket, or left hanging out of a hip pocket (where American men commonly carry a wallet).  The pair weighs only a couple ounces (50+ grams), and while not extremely durable, they're at least as good as house slippers for foot protection and durability -- plus, they're inexpensive (around $10, based on a quick Google search).

Answer (score 1):

What I do is, I have a [rollers bag](https://d16wp86s16nsnf.cloudfront.net/skatehut/product/872d4e5c.Rio%20Roller%20Skate%20Bag%20-%20Passion.jpg/750x750.fit.Rio%20Roller%20Skate%20Bag%20-%20Passion.jpg) and a backpack.

When I'm walking I have the rollers and the backpack inside the rollers bag.

And when I'm skating I have my shoes and the roller bag inside my backpack. I find the backpack more comfortable while skating than the rollers bag because is perfectly attached and not laterally moving.